# Estimating a mean from a game of ruin

Tags: probability

Camilla plays a casino game that has a fixed bet, fixed odds, and no skill, with a starting bankroll, $M_0$.  She plays until she can no longer afford to bet and records in a journal only her bankroll and how many bets she was able to make, $N_0$, until she could not afford to bet.  She has amnesia from drinking too many free drinks at the casino so remembers nothing else about the game.  Each day she goes back to the casino with a larger bankroll, $M_i$, plays the same game until she can no longer afford to bet, records her bankroll and how many bets she made, $N_i$ , drinks too much, and suffers amnesia again forgetting everything else about the game.  **Can she determine the true return of the game using only the information in her journal ?**

Additional info: the distribution of the game has non-negative discrete support, potentially unbounded, potentially including any given real number >= 0, has zero weight on infinity, mean less than 1, and finite variance.  Camilla's method of estimating the mean may not use information about the support she could have learned from playing the game unless she intuits it from the only information about the game she is allowed to use (the sequences $\{M_i\}$, and $\{N_i\}$) and the additional assumptions listed here.  She does not even know the bet of the game.

Comment: Does the procedure terminate after a finite number of days?

Comment: if she can determine the true EV in finite days, sure, but if not she may try forever, or at least as many days as are necessary to get within $\epsilon$.

Comment: She obviously can't do it in finite time.  It's possible that she loses every game, even though there's a positive chance of winning.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree

Comment: Even in infinite time, I think the most you'd be able to say is that the average outcome converges to the expected value with probability one.

Comment: what is the average outcome? convergence with probability 1 is more than acceptable.

Comment: Sorry, I was just making a general statement.  I meant that this is the best one can hope for, not that I have solved the problem.  Let me ask a question, though.  We can assume that the gambler always bets one dollar, and that the probability of winning is always $p$.  When she wins, does she win one dollar, or might it be some other amount?

Comment: we can assume she always bets one dollar, but the distribution of wins could be any non-negative discrete distribution. it could be like yours, or so she could win 30 cents, 0 cents, 1 dollar, $100,000, etc. the EV should be less than 1, no probability should be placed on infinity, but otherwise the distribution could even be unbounded. In other words she is not necessarily playing a Bernoulli trial, but the distribution is the same each time she goes back to the game.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "determine" and "get within $\epsilon$"? She can get arbitrarily accurate estimates of the expected value by using increasing bankrolls and dividing each bankroll by the number of bets placed -- the more difficult question is whether she can assess the accuracy she's reached. (I think the answer to this, too, is affirmative; she should be able to deduce this from the fluctuations in the results; but this will be more complicated to prove rigorously than just the fact that the estimates eventually become arbitrarily accurate (with accuracy unknown to her).)

Comment: "She can get arbitrarily accurate estimates of the expected value by using increasing bankrolls and dividing each bankroll by the number of bets placed " can you prove this? i think you are looking for 1 - that term... either way

Comment: @Alek: There are others on this site who are more versed in these kinds of proofs; for me it would be a slightly tedious exercise in rigour that I wouldn't enjoy :-) It seems clear intuitively, though -- asymptotically, the standard deviation of the number of bets it takes to lose the entire bankroll should increase with the square root of the bankroll, so the standard deviation of the number of bets it takes to lose a dollar should decrease with the inverse square root of the bankroll. There are some details to attend to because of the division, but I can't see how they could ruin the proof.

Comment: Let $p$ be the probability of winning a round. For each $i\geqslant 1$ we have
$$
\mathbb P(N_i = i + 2k) = \frac i{i+2k}\binom{i+2k}k(1-p)^kp^{i+k},\ k=0,1,\ldots
$$
and hence
$$
\mathbb E[N_i] = \frac i{1-2(1-p)}.
$$
If $M_i=m$ for all $i$ then statistical inference could be made as to the true value of $p$, but if $M_0<M_1<\cdots$ then I don't believe there is enough information to make a conclusion.